# Update dataframe values that match a regex condition and keep remaining values intact

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The following is an excerpt from my dataframe:

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]:
     LongName   BigDog   
1     Big Dog        1  
2     Mastiff        0    
3     Big Dog        1   
4         Cat        0
```

I want to use regex to update BigDog values to 1 if LongName is a mastiff. I need other values to stay the same. I tried this, and although it assigns 1 to mastiffs, it nulls all other values instead of keeping them intact.

```
def BigDog(longname): 
    if re.search('(?i)mastiff', longname):
        return '1'

df['BigDog'] = df['LongName'].apply(BigDog)
```

I'm not sure what to do, could anybody please help?

Comment: When you say stay the same, what values are you wanting to keep in your example?

Comment: I'd like the values in BigDog to turn into 1 1 1 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop or apply, use `str.match` with `DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['LongName'].str.match('(?i)mastiff'), 'BigDog'] = 1

  LongName  BigDog
1  Big Dog       1
2  Mastiff       1
3  Big Dog       1
4      Cat       0
```

Comment: This is so much easier than how I was attempting to do it, thank you! I just changed it to str.contains() as that fits my purposes better